# How to select entire content in Geb?

Tags: geb

Suppose I would like to write a Module, which can catch both data from `<input>` tag and as raw:

```
<div>Value1</div>
<div><input type="text" value="Value2"></div>
...
```

and I write

```
class MaybeInput extends Module {

    static content = {

        hasInput {
            if( $("input").length )
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        nav {
            if( hasInput ) {
                $("input")
            }
            {
                // return entire content! how?
            }
        }



    }

}
```

so that I can catch with

```
static content = {
   elem {
       i -> $("div", i).module(MaybeInput)
   }
}
```

How to return entire content in `MaybeInput`?

Comment: What do you mean by "return entire content"? How would you want to use `elem` from your definition when it contains an input and when not? Can you give an example? I struggle to understand why you would want to have a content definition that sometimes returns one type and sometimes the other.

Comment: @Mr Lister  try to use `$(":root")` to return everything